# How to make the text display up to five lines, and complete the collapse effect through CSS or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi everyone I encountered a problem, but my English is not very good, but I will try my best to express it completely.

The problem is that I have a requirement. The requirement of the design draft is that the text should show up to five lines of text. When it is exceeded, a button will appear to expand more text!
But my JS is not very familiar and only a little bit. I wonder if this effect can be achieved by using CSS alone?

If you also know how js is implemented, welcome to share it with me~
Thank you for your help first, I really don’t know how to do it, thank you.

```css
.content {
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
}

.more {
  text-align: center;
}
.more a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <p class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit odit fugit debitis, quibusdam esse eius ullam odio cupiditate cumque nostrum asperiores libero, sapiente aliquid animi? Saepe eligendi doloremque possimus. Velit sunt earum aliquam debitis quos eum atque nemo eius, hic quas doloremque facere et voluptatibus voluptatum eaque corrupti impedit ipsum beatae incidunt sapiente aliquid animi? Saepe eligendi doloremque possimus. Velit sunt earum aliquam debitis quos eum atque nemo eius, hic quas doloremque facere et voluptatibus voluptatum eaque corrupti impedit ipsum beatae incidunt sapiente aliquid animi? Saepe eligendi doloremque possimus. Velit sunt earum aliquam debitis quos eum atque nemo eius, hic quas doloremque facere et voluptatibus voluptatum eaque corrupti impedit ipsum beatae incidunt 
  </p>
  
  <div class="more">
    <a href="javaScript:;" class="show">V</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do that, try this:

```js
$('.show').click(function(){
  $(this).remove(); // remove more button
  $('.content').addClass('show-all'); // add class .show-all for .content when clicked on more button
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
}
.content.show-all{
  height:auto;
  overflow:visible;
  text-overflow: none
}
.more {
  text-align: center;
}
.more a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  <p class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit odit fugit debitis, quibusdam esse eius ullam odio cupiditate cumque nostrum asperiores libero, sapiente aliquid animi? Saepe eligendi doloremque possimus. Velit sunt earum aliquam debitis quos eum atque nemo eius, hic quas doloremque facere et voluptatibus voluptatum eaque corrupti impedit ipsum beatae incidunt sapiente aliquid animi? Saepe eligendi doloremque possimus. Velit sunt earum aliquam debitis quos eum atque nemo eius, hic quas doloremque facere et voluptatibus voluptatum eaque corrupti impedit ipsum beatae incidunt sapiente aliquid animi? Saepe eligendi doloremque possimus. Velit sunt earum aliquam debitis quos eum atque nemo eius, hic quas doloremque facere et voluptatibus voluptatum eaque corrupti impedit ipsum beatae incidunt 
  </p>
  
  <div class="more">
    <a href="javaScript:;" class="show">V</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here as an example with only css.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #646464;
  color: #fff;
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.panel-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  left: 30%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 40%;
}

.show, .hide {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1em;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show:target {
  display: none;
}

.show:target ~ .hide {
  display: block;
}

.show:target ~ .panel {
  max-height: 2000px;
}

.show:target ~ .fade {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.panel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}

.fade {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(100, 100, 100, 0) 0%, #646464 75%);
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>CSS Only: Show More</header>
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <a href="#show" class="show btn" id="show">Show Full Article</a> 
  <a href="#hide" class="hide btn" id="hide">Hide Full Article</a> 
  <div class="panel">
    Let us not wallow in the valley of despair, I say to you today, my friends.

And so even though we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American dream.

I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal."

I have a dream that one day on the red hills of Georgia, the sons of former slaves and the sons of former slave owners will be able to sit down together at the table of brotherhood.

I have a dream that one day even the state of Mississippi, a state sweltering with the heat of injustice, sweltering with the heat of oppression, will be transformed into an oasis of freedom and justice.

I have a dream that my four little children will one day live in a nation where they will not be judged by the color of their skin but by the content of their character.

I have a dream today!

I have a dream that one day, down in Alabama, with its vicious racists, with its governor having his lips dripping with the words of "interposition" and "nullification" -- one day right there in Alabama little black boys and black girls will be able to join hands with little white boys and white girls as sisters and brothers.

I have a dream today!

I have a dream that one day every valley shall be exalted, and every hill and mountain shall be made low, the rough places will be made plain, and the crooked places will be made straight; "and the glory of the Lord shall be revealed and all flesh shall see it together."2

This is our hope, and this is the faith that I go back to the South with.

With this faith, we will be able to hew out of the mountain of despair a stone of hope. With this faith, we will be able to transform the jangling discords of our nation into a beautiful symphony of brotherhood. With this faith, we will be able to work together, to pray together, to struggle together, to go to jail together, to stand up for freedom together, knowing that we will be free one day.

And this will be the day -- this will be the day when all of God's children will be able to sing with new meaning:

My country 'tis of thee, sweet land of liberty, of thee I sing.

Land where my fathers died, land of the Pilgrim's pride,

From every mountainside, let freedom ring!

And if America is to be a great nation, this must become true.

And so let freedom ring from the prodigious hilltops of New Hampshire.

Let freedom ring from the mighty mountains of New York.

Let freedom ring from the heightening Alleghenies of Pennsylvania.

Let freedom ring from the snow-capped Rockies of Colorado.

Let freedom ring from the curvaceous slopes of California.

But not only that:

Let freedom ring from Stone Mountain of Georgia.

Let freedom ring from Lookout Mountain of Tennessee.

Let freedom ring from every hill and molehill of Mississippi.

From every mountainside, let freedom ring.

And when this happens, and when we allow freedom ring, when we let it ring from every village and every hamlet, from every state and every city, we will be able to speed up that day when all of God's children, black men and white men, Jews and Gentiles, Protestants and Catholics, will be able to join hands and sing in the words of the old Negro spiritual:

                Free at last! Free at last!

                Thank God Almighty, we are free at last!
    
  </div><!-- end panel -->
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div><!-- end panel-wrapper -->
```